# split strings and rearrange a data frame

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a data like this one

```
df <- structure(list(A = structure(c(2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("", "NZT1", "O749", "P42I;QJ0;AIH2", "P609;QT7", 
"Q835", "Q854"), class = "factor"), B = structure(c(8L, 6L, 5L, 
7L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "P079;P0C7;P0C8", "P641;Q614", 
"Q013", "Q554", "Q749", "Q955", "Q9U0"), class = "factor"), C = structure(c(7L, 
8L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("P641;QS14", "P679;P0C7;P048", 
"Q168", "Q413", "Q550", "Q6N9", "Q980", "Q997"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

#              A              B              C
#1          NZT1           Q9U0           Q980
#2          O749           Q749           Q997
#3          Q835           Q554           Q6N9
#4          Q854           Q955           Q550
#5      P609;QT7           Q013           Q168
#6 P42I;QJ0;AIH2      P641;Q614           Q413
#7               P079;P0C7;P0C8      P641;QS14
#8                              P679;P0C7;P048
```

I am trying to split them based on ";", and then put them under the other string , the expected output I seek is like this

```
#            A              B              C
#1          NZT1           Q9U0           Q980
#2          O749           Q749           Q997
#3          Q835           Q554           Q6N9
#4          Q854           Q955           Q550
#5          P609           Q013           Q168
#6          QT7            P641           Q413
#7          P42I           Q614           P641
#8          QJ0            P079           QS14
#9          AIH2           P0C7           P679    
#10                        P0C8           P0C7      
#11                                       P048
```

I tried to use `strsplit()` but I did not get that far

This is what I tried

```
myNewdf <- strsplit(as.character(unlist(df)), ";")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try this:

```
x <- lapply(df, function (x) unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ";")))
```

This gives you a list. If you want a data frame, you need some further work to pad empty string `""`:

```
m <- max(lengths(x))
y <- as.data.frame(lapply(x, function (vec) c(vec, character(m - length(vec)))))

#       A    B    C
# 1  NZT1 Q9U0 Q980
# 2  O749 Q749 Q997
# 3  Q835 Q554 Q6N9
# 4  Q854 Q955 Q550
# 5  P609 Q013 Q168
# 6   QT7 P641 Q413
# 7  P42I Q614 P641
# 8   QJ0 P079 QS14
# 9  AIH2 P0C7 P679
# 10      P0C8 P0C7
# 11           P048
```

Comment: @Zheyuan Li I accept your answer, thanks but would be nice if you could also write some definition to your script so that I will learn from it

Answer (score 4):

The `scan` function will succeed here although the `as.data.frame` will choke if the number of items in each column are not the same:

```
as.data.frame(lapply( df, function(x) scan( text=as.character(x) , what="", sep=";", blank.lines.skip = FALSE))
+ )
Read 11 items
Read 11 items
Read 11 items
      A    B    C
1  NZT1 Q9U0 Q980
2  O749 Q749 Q997
3  Q835 Q554 Q6N9
4  Q854 Q955 Q550
5  P609 Q013 Q168
6   QT7 P641 Q413
7  P42I Q614 P641
8   QJ0 P079 QS14
9  AIH2 P0C7 P679
10      P0C8 P0C7
11           P048
```

Comment: `scan` is actually the heart of all the `read.*` functions. It's a low level function but it can do other tasks like mulit-line reads with appropriate parameters to the `what` argument.

Comment: Actually using it to read individual vectors, and that use-strategy has many examples on SO and Rhelp. I learned it from answers by G.Grothendieck.

Comment: In the old days we gave `scan` or `read.*` functions a `textConnection()` argument, and you may still need to do such with `readLines` since it is not based on `scan`.

Comment: I thought I made that point clear. You would need to construct another method to pad the shorter items with rep("", length-max.length).

Comment: `textConnection` is very simple. It just turns a vector into something that most functions will see as a file. Try: `x <- "1\n2\n3\n"; read.table(textConnection(x))`. Or: `y <- "1 a\n2 b\n3 c\n"; read.table(textConnection(y))`

Answer (score 2):

Or using the `ts` function:

```
lst <- lapply(df, function(a) unlist(strsplit(as.character(a), split = ";"))) # 1
tsr <- cbind(ts(lst$A), ts(lst$B), ts(lst$C)) # 2
tsr[is.na(tsr)] <- "" # 3
newDF <- as.data.frame(tsr) # 4
colnames(newDF) <- colnames(df) # 5 (if needed)

      # A    B    C
# 1  NZT1 Q9U0 Q980
# 2  O749 Q749 Q997
# 3  Q835 Q554 Q6N9
# 4  Q854 Q955 Q550
# 5  P609 Q013 Q168
# 6   QT7 P641 Q413
# 7  P42I Q614 P641
# 8   QJ0 P079 QS14
# 9  AIH2 P0C7 P679
# 10      P0C8 P0C7
# 11           P048
```

1. `lst` will give a list of `;` separated columns
2. `tsr` is a column-wise binding of time series objects. Time series objects are used to take care of unequal lengths.
3. find `NA`s in `tsr` and make them none value.
4. convert to data frame.
5. make column names of `newDF` the same as `df`, if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option with `stri_list2matrix`.  This returns a `matrix` with NA as missing values.  If we need `''`, use the `fill=''` argument in `stri_list2matrix`.  Also, this can be converted to `data.frame` with `as.data.frame`.

```
 library(stringi)
 stri_list2matrix(lapply(df, function(x) unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ";"))))
```

Comment: @nik As the question is put on hold, others can't add answers.  We will wait for the person (Procrastinatus ) to respond to your comments.

Comment: `stri_list2matrix` will give a matrix of characters with `NA` as missing values. Is that what OP is asked for?

Comment: @m0h3n  You can change it to `''` using the `fill` argument.  Also, the `as.data.frame` can convert it to `data.frame`

Comment: So better to point them out in the answer itself. I think you would remember your comment from yesterday [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204034/round-all-float-numbers-in-a-string/38205604#38205604). :-)