# Replacing number in a string with rounded number using regex

Tags: r, regex, replace, stringr

I have a data frame that includes comments from different people (so it can be written in any form they want). The sample data frame is shown below (this is only a sample and my original data set has more than 50000 rows):

```
structure(list(comment = c("3.22%-1ST $100K/1.15% BAL", "3.25% ON 1ST $100,000/1.1625% ON BAL", 
"3.225% 1ST 100K/1.1625 ON BAL", "3.22% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL", 
"3.255% 1ST 100K/1.1625% ON BAL", "3.2% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL", 
"3.22% ON 1ST 100K & 1.15% ON BALANCE", "3.255% 1ST 100K/1.1625% ON BAL", 
"3.22% ON 1ST 100K / 1.1625% ON BAL", "3.2% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL", 
"3.2% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL", "3.2% 1ST $100K + 1.1625% BALANCE", 
"3.255% ON 1ST $100K & 1.1625% ON BALANCE", "3.225% ON 1ST $100,000 AND 1.16% ON BALANCE", 
"3.255% ON FIRST $100,000 AND 1.1625% ON BALANCE", "$4000", "$7,500", 
"$6,000", "$5,000", "$6000.00", "$10,000 PLUS BONUS $10,000", 
"4-100/1.1625", "3.2% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL", "3.2% ON 1ST $100,000 + 1.15% ON BAL", 
"THE GREATER $3,000 OR .5% OF SALE PRICE", "**3.255% ON THE 1ST $100,000 AND 1.1625% ON THE BALANCE"
), a = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 
-26L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

 1 3.22%-1ST $100K/1.15% BAL            TRUE 
 2 3.25% ON 1ST $100,000/1.1625% ON BAL TRUE 
 3 3.225% 1ST 100K/1.1625 ON BAL        TRUE 
 4 3.22% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL          TRUE 
 5 3.255% 1ST 100K/1.1625% ON BAL       TRUE 
 6 3.2% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL           TRUE 
 7 3.22% ON 1ST 100K & 1.15% ON BALANCE TRUE 
 8 3.255% 1ST 100K/1.1625% ON BAL       TRUE 
 9 3.22% ON 1ST 100K / 1.1625% ON BAL   TRUE 
10 3.2% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL           TRUE 
11 ............................         ....
```

As you can see this data frame has no specific format and that makes it difficult to work with.
**What I want to do:** I want to change all number like 3.255%, 3.2%, 3.22%, 4, etc (basically, numbers in a range of 0 to 5 in each of the comments to the same format like `x.yz%` format.

**What are the challenges?** the main challenge here is that some rows don't start with numbers like $4000 or "THE GREATER $3,000 OR .5% OF SALE PRICE" which are obviously in a different format. One approach is to separate rows that start with a digit and label them with "TRUE" or "FALSE" for now. I wrote the command below(**not sure if this is a good idea, though!**):

```
df_com$a <- str_detect(df_com$comment, pattern = "^\\d")
```

However, using this we may miss a line like "THE GREATER $3,000 OR .5% OF SALE PRICE". This line should be changed to "THE GREATER $3,000 OR **.50**% OF SALE PRICE".

Also, in order to replace number and round them, I followed the answer explained here: [round all float numbers in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204034/round-all-float-numbers-in-a-string) and modified it in the form shown below to do the task:

```
gsubfn("(\\d\\w{1:3})", ~format(round(as.numeric(x), 2), nsmall=2), x)
```

However, this expression doesn't work.

The expected result is something in this form:

```
1 3.22%-1ST $100K/1.15% BAL              TRUE 
2 3.25% ON 1ST $100,000/1.16% ON BAL     TRUE 
3 3.23% 1ST 100K/1.16 ON BAL             TRUE 
4 3.22% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL            TRUE 
5 3.26% 1ST 100K/1.16% ON BAL            TRUE 
6 3.20% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL            TRUE 
7 3.22% ON 1ST 100K & 1.15% ON BALANCE   TRUE 
8 3.26% 1ST 100K/1.16% ON BAL            TRUE 
9 3.22% ON 1ST 100K / 1.16% ON BAL       TRUE 
10 3.20% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL           TRUE 
11 ............................         ....
```

Any advice on how I can do this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_replace_all` from the {stringr} package and use a function as `replacement` argument. See my updated answer below if it fits your needs.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dat <- structure(list(comment = c("3.22%-1ST $100K/1.15% BAL", "3.25% ON 1ST $100,000/1.1625% ON BAL", 
                                  "3.225% 1ST 100K/1.1625 ON BAL", "3.22% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL", 
                                  "3.255% 1ST 100K/1.1625% ON BAL", "3.2% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL", 
                                  "3.22% ON 1ST 100K & 1.15% ON BALANCE", "3.255% 1ST 100K/1.1625% ON BAL", 
                                  "3.22% ON 1ST 100K / 1.1625% ON BAL", "3.2% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL", 
                                  "3.2% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL", "3.2% 1ST $100K + 1.1625% BALANCE", 
                                  "3.255% ON 1ST $100K & 1.1625% ON BALANCE", "3.225% ON 1ST $100,000 AND 1.16% ON BALANCE", 
                                  "3.255% ON FIRST $100,000 AND 1.1625% ON BALANCE", "$4000", "$7,500", 
                                  "$6,000", "$5,000", "$6000.00", "$10,000 PLUS BONUS $10,000", 
                                  "4-100/1.1625", "3.2% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL", "3.2% ON 1ST $100,000 + 1.15% ON BAL", 
                                  "THE GREATER $3,000 OR .5% OF SALE PRICE", "**3.255% ON THE 1ST $100,000 AND 1.1625% ON THE BALANCE"
), a = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
         TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
         FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                       -26L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

dat2 <- dat %>% 
  mutate(comment2 =
           str_replace_all(comment,
                           "[0-9]\\.[0-9]*",
                           function(x) format(round(as.numeric(x), 2), nsmall = 2)) %>% 
           str_replace_all("\\s\\.[0-9]*",
                           function(x) paste0(" ", format(round(as.numeric(x), 2), nsmall = 2))) %>% 
           str_replace_all("([0-9])-",
                           "\\1.00%-")
  ) 

tail(dat2)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   comment                               a     comment2                          
#>   <chr>                                 <lgl> <chr>                             
#> 1 $10,000 PLUS BONUS $10,000            FALSE $10,000 PLUS BONUS $10,000        
#> 2 4-100/1.1625                          TRUE  4.00%-100/1.16                    
#> 3 3.2% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL            TRUE  3.20% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL       
#> 4 3.2% ON 1ST $100,000 + 1.15% ON BAL   TRUE  3.20% ON 1ST $100,000 + 1.15% ON ~
#> 5 THE GREATER $3,000 OR .5% OF SALE PR~ FALSE THE GREATER $3,000 OR 0.50% OF SA~
#> 6 **3.255% ON THE 1ST $100,000 AND 1.1~ FALSE **3.26% ON THE 1ST $100,000 AND 1~
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, @TimTeaFan. This is also a great solution. There is only one point I want to mention and that's regarding row 22 and 23. In these rows have `4-100/1.1625` and `THE GREATER $3,000 OR .5% OF SALE PRICE` which should be changed to `4.00%-100/1.16%` and `THE GREATER $3,000 OR .50% OF SALE PRICE` is there anyway to change `[0-9]\\.[0-9]*` somehow to capture these changes as well?

Comment: Thanks, this will generate the exact same result as I expected, thanks for the update

Answer (score 3):

In base R, this is a great place to use `gregexpr` and `regmatches`:

```r
gre <- gregexpr("\\b?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*(?=%)", df_com$comment, perl = TRUE)
str(regmatches(df_com$comment, gre))
# List of 26
#  $ : chr [1:2] "3.22" "1.15"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "3.25" "1.16"
#  $ : chr "3.23"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "3.22" "1.15"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "3.25" "1.16"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "3.20" "1.15"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "3.22" "1.15"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "3.25" "1.16"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "3.22" "1.16"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "3.20" "1.15"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "3.20" "1.15"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "3.20" "1.16"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "3.25" "1.16"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "3.23" "1.16"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "3.25" "1.16"
#  $ : chr(0) 
#  $ : chr(0) 
#  $ : chr(0) 
#  $ : chr(0) 
#  $ : chr(0) 
#  $ : chr(0) 
#  $ : chr(0) 
#  $ : chr [1:2] "3.20" "1.15"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "3.20" "1.15"
#  $ : chr(0) 
#  $ : chr [1:2] "3.25" "1.16"
regmatches(df_com$comment, gre) <-
  lapply(regmatches(df_com$comment, gre), function(nums) {
    format(round(as.numeric(nums), 2), nsmall=2)
  })
```

The result:

```r
df_com
# # A tibble: 26 x 2
#    comment                              a    
#    <chr>                                <lgl>
#  1 3.22%-1ST $100K/1.15% BAL            TRUE 
#  2 3.25% ON 1ST $100,000/1.16% ON BAL   TRUE 
#  3 3.23% 1ST 100K/1.1625 ON BAL         TRUE 
#  4 3.22% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL          TRUE 
#  5 3.25% 1ST 100K/1.16% ON BAL          TRUE 
#  6 3.20% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL          TRUE 
#  7 3.22% ON 1ST 100K & 1.15% ON BALANCE TRUE 
#  8 3.25% 1ST 100K/1.16% ON BAL          TRUE 
#  9 3.22% ON 1ST 100K / 1.16% ON BAL     TRUE 
# 10 3.20% 1ST 100K/1.15% ON BAL          TRUE 
# # ... with 16 more rows
```

I used the literal of `x.yz%`, which explains why there is a single `1.1625` unchanged in row 3.

Comment: thanks so much for the effort you put into this. I just have a couple of questions if you don't mind. Based on `\\b?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*(?=%)` in your code, I am guessing that you are defining a number in a form of `xbdh.hkdv`, is this correct? If yes, I am afraid that this pattern wouldn't cover cases like "4" in row 22 or "0.5" in row 23.  Can you please explain how `\\b?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*(?=%)` works? I am new to `regular expression` any clarification helps me a lot. Also, I was not sure why 1.1625 hasn't been changed to 1.16.

Comment: I understand that we can't do everything in one step, so probably we have to write a separate code for those cases, but I just wanted to know every step you took in your solution. Thanks again in advance for your clarification

Comment: Per my last comment, `1.1625` isn't caught because of your `"x.yz%"`. If `%` is not required, you can remove `(?=%)` and `perl=TRUE`.

Comment: Got you. Thanks @r2evans