# Round numeric values in comma-separated string column

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to round values in a comma-separated string column:

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:8,
                     value = c("0.0081007", NA, NA,"0.00699123", 
                               "0.175555, 0.106897, 0.0289, 0.255005", 
                               NA, NA, "0.0047777, 0.8970001")), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I can do it as shown below but doubt that this is the most concise/most efficient way:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(value = lapply(str_extract_all(value, "[\\d.]+"), function(x) round(as.numeric(x), 3))) %>%
  unnest(value) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(
    value = toString(value))
# A tibble: 8 × 2
     id value                     
  <int> <chr>                     
1     1 0.008                     
2     2 NA                        
3     3 NA                        
4     4 0.007                     
5     5 0.176, 0.107, 0.029, 0.255
6     6 NA                        
7     7 NA                        
8     8 0.005, 0.897
```

Is there a shorter/more concise `dplyr` way?

Comment: You could also use the top answer from this question inside of a single mutate line, but that does require another library and might be less intuitive for somebody to see what is going on. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204034/round-all-float-numbers-in-a-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make this a bit more concise with `separate_rows()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(value, sep = ",", convert = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(value = toString(round(value, 3)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Look, Mum, no `tidyverse`!

```
df$value <- sapply(
    sprintf('round(c(%s), 3)', df$value), 
    \(x) { toString(eval(str2expression(x)))  }
)

df

# # A tibble: 8 x 2
#      id value                     
#   <int> <chr>                     
# 1     1 0.008                     
# 2     2 NA                        
# 3     3 NA                        
# 4     4 0.007                     
# 5     5 0.176, 0.107, 0.029, 0.255
# 6     6 NA                        
# 7     7 NA                        
# 8     8 0.005, 0.897
```

Comment: Or re-tidyversed... `df %>% mutate(value = map_chr(sprintf("round(c(%s), 3)", value), ~ toString(eval(str2expression(.x)))))` (I couldn't help myself!). Nice answer.

Comment: @Adam have been thinking about it :) and base pipes `|>` are one symbol shorter

Comment: Ah, mum, speaking of non-tidyverse: `df$value <- sapply(strsplit(df$value, ", "), function(x) round(as.numeric(x), 3))` will work perfectly on a dataframe such as `df <- data.frame(id = 1:8, value = c("0.0081007", NA, NA,"0.00699123", 
 "0.175555, 0.106897, 0.0289, 0.255005",  NA, NA, "0.0047777, 0.8970001"))` and looks a lot neater to me, Mum!

Comment: Oh and I always thought easyness, or brevity, or ciciseness were a value in coding ...

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Sorry, for not being the part of the congregation. I agree that your solution is more appropriate for this case. However, it is conceptually the same as an [answer given by Adam.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70336454/1861328) And this is exactly the reason I rejected to post this solution. It might not be very useful for your particular case, but for me, and alike who are learning to work with expressions, substitutions, function factories etc. it might be a good starting point.

Comment: no worries man, just saying ...